# Access javascript variables in namespace from different files

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write '3rd-party loading' Javascript, similar to Stripe, Disqus and others. The idea is to access a variable as configuration and be able to interact with it.

So, in the head of my app I have 2 scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/domain/ks.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Ks.setConfiguration("flow2");
</script>
```

**ks.js**

```
if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
  // The document has finished loading. We can now access the DOM elements.
  Kb.setup();
}

var Kb = new function() {
  // public
  this.setConfiguration = function(key) {
    var APP_KEY = key;
  }

  this.setup = function() {
    checkConfiguration(APP_KEY);
    internalFunction();
  };

  // private
  var internalFunction = function() {
    console.log("calling private function from namespace");
  };

  var checkConfiguration = function(key) {
    // log message if key not set
    console.log(key);
  };
};
```

The problem is I can't access `APP_KEY` variable in the main script.
What I'm looking to accomplish is load main script async, set up configuration and then interact with configuration items.

Comment: it's unclean what you actually want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

Either add an `this.getAppKey()` but you **have to** define the `APP_KEY` inside the `var Kb = new function()` and not inside the closure.

It will still work because of the way [var works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), but for clarity of code add it to the "class" level scope.

Or you can declare it as `this.APP_KEY` and access it from `<instance>.APP_KEY`.

Or you can make the `Kb()` into a module and havee the `APP_KEY` in a scope where you can [export it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Examples:

somefile.js

```
var Kb = new function() {
  var APP_KEY = null; // this is defined on a higher scope
  this.PUBLIC_APP_KEY = null; // with this you can call directly the key if you need to access it

  // public
  this.setConfiguration = function(key) {
    APP_KEY = key;
    this.PUBLIC_APP_KEY = key;
  }

  this.getKey = function() {
      return APP_KEY;
  }

  this.setup = function() {
    checkConfiguration(APP_KEY);
    internalFunction();
  };

  // private
  var internalFunction = function() {
    console.log("calling private function from namespace");
  };

  var checkConfiguration = function(key) {
    // log message if key not set
    console.log(key);
  };
};
```

now in some other file you can do

```
if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
  var kb = Kb();
   kb.setConfiguration(<somekey>);
   console.log(kb.getKey()); // <somekey>
   console.log(kb.PUBLIC_APP_KEY) // <somekey>
  // The document has finished loading. We can now access the DOM elements.
  Kb.setup(); 
}
```

Or, finally, you could do something like this

```
// somefile.js
var key = "key";
// export it
exports.API_KEY = key;
```

and in some other file

```
import { API_KEY } from "somefile.js"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not advanced enough to put all pieces together. Could you provide a snippet?

Comment: Sure. Will change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. However, `document.readyState === 'interactive'` does not run the external file, and without it raises an error since `Kb` namespace is not loaded yet. Any suggestion?

Comment: @olivier you can remove it. It is just an example. To make it work you need to include in a `script` tag the file that you have saved the `Kb` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/domain/ks.js?callback=setConfig" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setConfig() {
    Ks.setConfiguration("flow2");
  }
</script>
```

The `setConfig` should be called once your script has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

Your `APP_KEY` is local to the `function`, that's why you are not able to access.

```
var _AAP_KEY; //private 

this.setConfiguration = function(key) {
    _AAP_KEY = key;
}
```

You need to have a `getter`:

```
this.getConfiguration = function() {
    return _AAP_KEY;
}
```